# push an element to an array with useState hooks

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to push new tag in useState how possible i can do that

```
const [mydata, setData] = useState({
    user_gender: "",
    user_relationship: "",
    user_birth_day: "",
    user_birth_month: "",
    user_gender_interest: "",
    user_birth_year: "",
    tags: []
  });

const handleAddChip = chip => {
    setData({
      ...mydata,
      tags: chip
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `updater` version of the setter provided by `useState` and `concat` to return a new array instead of `push`

```
const handleAddChip = chip => {
    setData(previousData =>({
       ...previousData,
       tags: previousData.tags.concat(chip)
     }));
};
```

You can also do it without the updater version, but usually isn't a good idea.

```
setData({...myData, tags: myData.tags.concat(chip)})
```

Comment: im getting this error Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: I've mispelled that. Should be `previousData.tags`. Now should work as expected