# How can I change an array in object in an array?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use React with material-ui framework. In documentation, there is [an example](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) of select with chip, which is made with an array. There, they remove and add values in the array this way:

```js
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setPersonName(event.target.value);
  };
```

I need to do the same, but modifying an array within an object within an array, like this :

```js
const [data, setData] = React.useState([{ someData: 'data', array: [1,2,3] }]);

const handleChange = event => {
    setData(???);
  };
```

I'd found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957355/push-an-element-to-an-array-with-usestate-hooks), but It doesn't work for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what data exactly will be passed in `event.target.value`? And how do you want to handle adding and removing? Or do you want all values from all inputs to be  in that `array`?

Answer (score 3):

You can map your state array and update it there

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([{ someData: 'data', array: [1,2,3] }]);

const handleChange = event => {
   setData(() => {
      return data.map((item) => {
         return {
            ...item,
            array: [...item.array, event.target.value]
         } 
     })
   });
};
```

First you would loop through each `item` in your `data` array and would return a new `data` array by modifying each `item` object in it.

[here is a working code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-monad-90yhg)

Comment: I've never saw such way to modify an array. Thanks! But it doesn't work for me because I also need to remove items from the array and your method is allowing only adding.

Comment: I'm using ES6 Syntax to modify the array, you do all sorts of things here. Let me know what exactly you need, I can give you some sample code.

Comment: To remove items from the array, instead of `array: [...item.array, event.target.value]`, you can filter the previous array elements like this: `array: [...item.array.filter(v => <some_condition_here>), event.target.value]`